# Converting complicated excel which containing images,drawings into pdf using java

Tags: java, excel, pdf, apache-poi, itext

can anyone please tell me whether it is possible to convert excel which containing images, drawings into pdf using poi and itext open source apis (openoffice not needed).

My code is as given below, the code works fine...but comes to complicated excel i'm not getting the exact pdf

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import com.itextpdf.text.Anchor;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chapter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Section;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class ExceltoPDF {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */

    private static String FILE = "C:\\Users\\Work\\Downloads\\OIS-Project Planning.pdf";
    private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
            Font.BOLD);
    private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
            Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
    private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
            Font.BOLD);
    private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
            Font.BOLD);
    //Find out number of columns in the excel 
    private static int numberOfColumns;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String excelFile = "C:\\Users\\Work\\Downloads\\OIS-Project Planning.xlsx";

        File xlsFile = new File(excelFile);
        Workbook workbook;
        try {
            workbook = loadSpreadSheet(xlsFile);
            readSpreadSheet(workbook);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Excel File (or) PDF File is already opened. Please close the file");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void readSpreadSheet(Workbook workbook) throws IOException,
            DocumentException {

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
        document.open();
        addMetaData(document);
        addTitlePage(document);

        Anchor anchor = new Anchor("First Chapter", catFont);
        anchor.setName("First Chapter");

        // Second parameter is the number of the chapter
        Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

        Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("Table", subFont);
        Section subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
        addEmptyLine(subPara, 5);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        int temp = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        PdfPTable table = null;

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            int cellNumber = 0;

            if (flag) {
                table = new PdfPTable(row.getLastCellNum());
                flag = false;
            }

            // For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {   
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
                    if (temp == 0) {            
                        numberOfColumns = row.getLastCellNum();
                        PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                                cell.getStringCellValue()));
                        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        table.addCell(c1);
                        table.setHeaderRows(1);

                    }else{
                        cellNumber =checkEmptyCellAndAddCellContentToPDFTable(cellNumber,cell,table);
                    }                   
                    cellNumber++;
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    cellNumber =checkEmptyCellAndAddCellContentToPDFTable(cellNumber,cell,table);
                    cellNumber++; 
                    break;
                }       
            }
            temp = 1;
            if(numberOfColumns != cellNumber){
                for(int i=0;i<(numberOfColumns-cellNumber);i++){
                    table.addCell(" ");
                }
            }
        }
        subCatPart.add(table);
        // Now add all this to the document
        document.add(catPart);
        document.close();
    }

    private static int checkEmptyCellAndAddCellContentToPDFTable(int cellNumber, Cell cell, PdfPTable table) {
        if (cellNumber == cell.getColumnIndex()) {
            if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
                table.addCell(Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
            }
            if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                table.addCell(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }

        } else {
            while( cellNumber < cell.getColumnIndex()) {

                    table.addCell(" ");
                    cellNumber++;

            }
            if (cellNumber == cell.getColumnIndex()) {
                if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
                    table.addCell(Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                }
                if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                    table.addCell(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }

            }
            cellNumber = cell.getColumnIndex();
        }   

        return cellNumber;
    }

    private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
        document.addTitle("My first PDF");
        document.addSubject("Using iText");
        document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
        document.addAuthor("Uvaraj");
        document.addCreator("Uvaraj");
    }

    private static void addTitlePage(Document document)
            throws DocumentException {
        Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
        // We add one empty line
        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        // Lets write a big header
        preface.add(new Paragraph("Title of the document", catFont));

        addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
        // Will create: Report generated by: _name, _date
        preface.add(new Paragraph("Report generated by: " + "Uvaraj" + ", "
                + new Date(), smallBold));
        addEmptyLine(preface, 3);
        preface.add(new Paragraph(
                "This document describes something which is very important ",
                smallBold));

        addEmptyLine(preface, 8);

        preface.add(new Paragraph(
                "This document is a preliminary version  ;-).", redFont));

        document.add(preface);
        // Start a new page
        document.newPage();
    }

    private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
        }
    }

    private static Workbook loadSpreadSheet(File xlsFile) throws Exception {
        Workbook workbook = null;

        String ext = getFileExtension(xlsFile.getName());
        if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
            OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(xlsFile.getAbsolutePath());
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
            pkg.close();
        } else if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
            InputStream xlsFIS = new FileInputStream(xlsFile);
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(xlsFIS);
            xlsFIS.close();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("FILE EXTENSION NOT RECOGNIZED");
        }
        return workbook;
    }

    private static String getFileExtension(String fileName) {
        String ext = "";
        int mid = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        ext = fileName.substring(mid + 1, fileName.length());
        System.out.println("File Extension --" + ext);
        return ext;
    }

}
```

Comment: As far as my experience goes none of the open source solutions work great on complex documents. I have not tried any paid solutions. One solution I had been thinking of is using MS excel / MS word object on a windows computer for doing the conversion. I never got a chance to implement it though.

Comment: @RaviH so we cant do this with any of java open source api

Comment: My interpretation of @RaviH's answer is "No, you're asking something that isn't possible with open source software" and that answer is in line with my own opinion.

Comment: I have done it with POI and itext, it is quite possible, but it is going to take more code than what you have (I have about 2K lines). Hint, don't use a PDF table, if you want to support things like merged cells, use ColumnText.

Comment: @TonyBenBrahim Can you please share me your code stuff

Comment: @Alex Man, I will see if my work will let me open source it, if so I will throw it up on github and let you know

Comment: @TonyBenBrahim okay.....that will be a great help for me