# Converting html to pdf in android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I converted .html to pdf file successfully. In that pdf file "image" cannot be write. what was the problem. I used the following jar files :

1. itextg-5.5.0.jar
2. xmlworker-5.4.1.jar
3. sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar
4. scpkix-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar
5. scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar

Below is my code :

```
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
            new FileOutputStream(sdPath + "ExcelToPdf.pdf"));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
            new FileInputStream(sdPath + "check.html"));
    // step 5
    document.close();
```

I got the pdf file with text but not with images..So how to write the images to pdf from html file... Is i need to replace any jar files ?? Any idea ?

Comment: See related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810965/converting-complicated-excel-which-containing-images-drawings-into-pdf-using-jav

Comment: @ BillyBigPotatoes : Here we are discussing about .html to pdf not excel to pdf.

Comment: Please don't mix the version numbers of iText and XmlWorker. They are the same for a reason.

Comment: And for the image problem: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html#itextdoc-menu-10